# Does UPDATE overwrite values if they are identical?

Tags: mysql

I only want to update a vale in my database if it is different. Reading through the Oracle docs on UPDATE, it says...

> ...the UPDATE statement updates columns of existing rows in the named table with **new** values.

Since it doesn't say it won't overwrite identical values, should I take this statement literally? Does this mean MySQL does some sort of Boolean matching check for me?

Comment: If an identical value does or does not get clobbered during an `UPDATE`, how would this affect you?  My guess is that an identical value _will_ get overwritten, because otherwise the database would have to do extra work to check for this.

Comment: If you send the data with update statement, then definately it will overwrite even if its same.

Comment: @Tim, I believe if engine updates identical rows it will run update trigger if one exists. This will affect user who create logs for data operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, MySQL won't overwrite identical values.

Lets say we insert some data:

```
insert into foo(id,val1,val2,val3) values (0,1,2,3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

If you update it with the same values:

```
update foo set id=0, val1=1, val2=2, val3=3 where id=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Take a look on servers response `0 rows affected`

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about the feedback. It's a useful thing and I'll be using it more often now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

an sql query would update even identical value by practically substituting them. Anyway, you can structure your sql to avoid it will substitute the identical value. (I think also that the latter way would be more time consuming then the normal procedure and maybe useless for the final result)